# Using React-Redux: How to Access Variables in the Store, within Nested Components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using React-Redux, but I am not able to figure out how to access a variable in the Redux store inside of my nested components.

How can I share a variable between components, using React-Redux?

For example:

I have an 'index.js' file and 30 nested components. Managing these components becomes difficult after a while.

I have a 'C1.js' component. Let's just say I wrote this code in it.

```
function Reducer(state = 'example' , action) {
    return state;
}
const store = createStore(Reducer)
```

index.js file:

```
<Provider store = {store}>
    <App/>, document.getElementById('root')
  </Provider>
```

How do I pass the 'store' variable to the 'C1.js' component to the index.js file?

Thanks...

Comment: Did you make some researches on how to use React + Redux?

Comment: I've researched your use, but I may not understand it because my English is a bit poor. Is this a correct use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something called "Connect" to connect your various components to the provider.

In the file that contains your C1.js component:

```
  import {connect} from 'react-redux'


  const MyComponent = () => {
      let someData = props.someData
      return(
        //all of your JSX for your component here
      )
  }

  const mapState = state => {
    return {
       someData: state.someData
    }
  }

export default connect(mapState)(MyComponent)
```

In the code above, notice the mapStateFunction.  Connect is hooking that up with the Provider, and the state that is on the Provider.  So that is where you are able to link whatever properties are on your Provider (React-Redux) state with this particular data.

Now, in your component, you will now have prop.someData

-

In the index file, you have your Provider in the wrong place, you need to change your code to this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

See, the difference there?  The  is the React Element (and all of its children that you are asking React to render to the DOM). It is the first parameter of the ReactDOM.render function.

The second parameter to the ReactDom.render function is the element in the DOM where you want it to put all of your React elements.

Comment: How do I pass the 'store' variable in the 'C1.js' component to the index.js file?

Answer (score 0):

You did not configure well redux and react. You need to go over the doc of redux to setup correctly. Should get working after that.